# RTK Query | Handling Path Variables

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Let's say I have the following endpoint: **[GET]** `"v2/users/{id}/recommendations/{type}"`
where `{id}` is the user's id, and `{type}` is one of the following values: `"movies"` | `"tv-shows"` | `"games"`.

Is there an official way in ***RTK Query*** to handle path variables like they do for query params, or do I need to format the string and inject the variables myself?
To be clearer, ***RTK Query*** handles query params like so:

```
query(params) {
   return {
      url: MY_ENDPOINT,
      method: 'PUT',
      params: params
   };
}
```

In above example, if `MY_ENDPOINT = "v2/users"` and `params = { id: 1234 }`, 
then the request will hit the endpoint `"v2/users?id=1234"`

I'm looking for a similar way but with path params - that I will pass the path params and it will format the endpoint's string with it and everything. How is it done in ***RTK Query***? What is the proper way to handle such requests using ***RTK Query***?

**P.S -** obviously I'm not talking about OS path variables, rather about this: [Spring @PathVariable Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable)

Answer (score 1):

```js
query(params) {
   return {
      url: `v2/users/${params.id}/recommendations/${params.type}`,
      method: 'PUT',
      params: params
   };
}
```

There is no way to create an api for this that would be simpler than you just using a template string for it.

Comment: So RTK Query doesn't support path variables natively? Also, what do I do if I pass a variable that holds the endpoint? Because I don't see that JS have any string.format method; do I have to use string.replace for this then? i.e, what do I do if my endpoint is stored in a variable like `MY_ENDPOINT: "v2/users/{id}/recommendations/{type}"`

Comment: If you would use a string like that, you would need to parse that string every time and apply string replacement on it. And you would need to ship code for that. That's very unneccesarily complicated for a task that could just be written inline, as I did show above - and that's why RTK Query does not ship anything for it. It would be extra bundle size for a feature without real benefit for most users. Really just write it inline, as I have shown.